# technical report citation in bibtex

Tags: bibtex

How can I remove the word (Technical report) from the output of bibtex when using Harvard style?

```
@techreport{doornik1994practical,
  title={A practical test for univariate and multivariate normality},
  author={Doornik, J.A. and Hansen, H.},
  year={1994},
  institution={Nuffield College, Oxford, UK, Discussion paper}
  type={~},
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you provide us with a minimal working example?

Comment: "Harvard" citation style, aka author-year citation style, is compatible with lots and lots of BibTeX bibliography styles -- which one do you use? (It's the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` command that's of interest.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a trick:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{doornik1994practical,
  title={A practical test for univariate and multivariate normality},
  author={Doornik, J.A. and Hansen, H.},
  year={1994},
  institution={Nuffield College, Oxford, UK, Discussion paper},
  type={\notype},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard}
\newcommand\notype[1]{\unskip}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I believe that “Discussion paper” *is* the type:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{doornik1994practical,
  title={A practical test for univariate and multivariate normality},
  author={Doornik, J.A. and Hansen, H.},
  year={1994},
  institution={Nuffield College, Oxford, UK},
  type={Discussion paper},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harvard}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I used the `filecontents*` environment just to make the example self contained. Use your normal method with a separate bib file.