# Adding working papers to biblatex-chicago bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biblatex-chicago

I would like to add working papers in my biblatex chicago bibliography. I would like list the working paper series and the paper's number. However, chicago style drops any reference to the working paper series.

**Setup:**

I am using biblatex-chicago with the following setup

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[authordate,
isbn=false,
url=false,
doi=false,
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=10,
block=space,
backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```

**Previous posts:**

I have found two workarounds, which both dont work for me. One manual one [Link 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325842/how-to-enter-workingpaper-in-biblatex-chicago) that uses reports. This solution prints technical report in the bibliography which is undesirable. The other one is this one, that is manual and would create a lot of manual effort in my >200 page dissertation document. [Link 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160459/technical-report-citation-in-bibtex/449102#449102)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit per request by Moewe:

I receive

Bagger, Jesper, Javier a Birchenall, Hani Masnsour, and Sergio Urzúa. 2013. Education, Birth Order, and Family Size. Technical report. Institute for the Study of Labor - IZA Discussion paper series

and I would like to receive:

Bagger, Jesper, Javier a Birchenall, Hani Masnsour, and Sergio Urzúa. 2013. Education, Birth Order, and Family Size. Working Paper No. 7454, Institute for the Study of Labor - IZA Discussion paper series:  [or something similar]

**Full configuration**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{float} % better control over placement of tables and figures in the text
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{setspace}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago} 
\bibliography{../../library}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
anchorcolor=blue,
citecolor=blue,
filecolor=blue,
menucolor=blue,
runcolor=blue,
urlcolor=blue
}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{0.5em} 
\setlength{\bibhang}{3em}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addcomma\space} 

\finalandcomma 
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{volume+number+eid}{%
setunit*{\adddot}%
}{%
}{}{}

\AtBeginBibliography{% 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
}
\usepackage[left=1.1in, right=1.1in, bottom=1.1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: The solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325842/how-to-enter-workingpaper-in-biblatex-chicago does not print the words 'technical report' in the bibliography for me, I get exactly the output as shown in the answer. What exactly did you try (please provide a full example document similar to what you find in the linked answer), what output did you get (show a picture) and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Note that the behaviour of `biblatex-chicago` is slightly non-standard here. The standard styles only support `type` and `number`, while `biblatex-chicago` supports `type`, `series` and `number`.

Comment: I think that the difference is that mendeley prints at_technicalreport and not _atreport. Here is an excerpt of the bibliography @techreport{Bagger2013,
author = {Bagger, Jesper and Birchenall, Javier a and Masnsour, Hani and Urz{\'{u}}a, Sergio},
booktitle = {IZA Discussion paper series},
title = {{Education, Birth Order, and Family Size}},
volume = {No. 7454},
year = {2013}
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Mendeley exports an entry like this

```
@techreport{Bagger2013,
 author = {Bagger, Jesper and Birchenall, Javier a and Masnsour, Hani and Urz{\'{u}}a, Sergio},
 booktitle = {IZA Discussion paper series},
 title = {{Education, Birth Order, and Family Size}},
 volume = {No. 7454},
 year = {2013}
}
```

Ideally you would use `@report` instead of `@techreport`, but `@techreport` is fine as well.

`@report`s should always have a `type` field. That field can hold the paper series or any other useful type specification. If `@techreport`s don't have a `type` field `biblatex` will substitute "technical report" instead; this is not the case for `@report` entries.

The number in a series goes into `number` and not `volume`.

`booktitle` is completely ignored.

A useful entry would look like

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[authordate,
isbn=false,
url=false,
doi=false,
maxcitenames=3,
maxbibnames=10,
block=space,
backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@techreport{Bagger2013,
  author      = {Jesper Bagger and Javier A. Birchenall and Hani Mansour and Sergio Urzúa},
  title       = {Education, Birth Order, and Family Size},
  date        = {2013-06},
  type        = {IZA Discussion paper},
  number      = {7454},
  institution = {Forschungsinstitut zur Zukunft der Arbeit},
  location    = {Bonn},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Bagger2013}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bagger, Jesper, Javier A. Birchenall, Hani Mansour, and Sergio Urzúa. 2013. Education, Birth Order, and Family Size. IZA Discussion paper 7454. Bonn: Forschungsinstitut zur Zukunft der Arbeit, June.]

Comment: Thank you - incredibly helpful - this solved my problem. For other users: Report type and number are not available by default when you add a report document type to your library. You can add type/number/etc. as categories via Tools > Options > Document Details. 

Mendeley does not export the Number into the .bib files but for me it also works to add the number to the "Type" of document. 

Moewe - you are the most helpful seagull out there. Thanks again!

Comment: @MaximilianS. Not that I am very confident that it will help, but you should contact the Mendeley developers about this. If they claim to support `biblatex` they really should allow `type` and `number` for `@report` or `@techreport`. Type is even a mandatory field.

Comment: They do so for at_techreport. Mendeley does not export at_report (imho). However, while I can enter for example Number : 14013, it is not exported into the bibliography file, which is strange, because Mendeley even exports the abstract by default ...  I shall send them our finding. Thanks again for your support.